# Karma/Jasmine forcing to import irrelevant components

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to do unit tests with karma/jasmine on Angular 4 project. I took one of the components, which is on the very bottom of the components tree, so I won't have many dependencies.

But unfortunately I still have a problem, I'm receiving errors to add not imported component, but when I'm adding it, it asks for another one, and than for another one and so on. I added 5 of them and still not there, I think I even shouldn't import components, which are totally not connected to the unit test...

Example error:

```
Error: Component ReportSelection is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
```

How to avoid something like this?

Current beforeEach() with commented out some of the unrelated components:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            InternalUserAccountSelectionComponent, ExactLengthValidatorDirective,
            //ReportSelection, ReportViewComponent, FrameComponent, DemoComponent, ItalyAnnualCommissionComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            HttpModule, FormsModule, TooltipModule.forRoot(), TypeaheadModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                    deps: [Http]
                }
            }),
        ],
        providers: [
            TranslateService, Api, Serializerer, Alert, LocalStorageService, BrowserCheck, SecurityService
        ],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InternalUserAccountSelectionComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```